# in safari browser songs does not play

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, html5-audio

In safari browser songs does not play. User clicks on button , and music has to play. In other browsers everything works fine. There is an error shows up

[image]

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.audio = createRef();
  }

setActiveState = activeState => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ activeState }, () => {
        this.props.toggleMenu(true);
        if (activeState === 2 && this.audio.current.paused) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.audio.current.volume = 0.3;
            this.audio.current.play();
            this.setEndState();
          }, 1700);
        }
      });
    }, 300);
  };

        <audio
          src="/static/files/smart-media.mp3"
          ref={this.audio}
          loop
          preload="metadata"
          type="audio/mpeg"
        />
```

Comment: You need to mark your audio element as "allowed by the user to make sound" from **inside** an user-gesture event. Once it's done, you'll be able to play it as you wish. One trick is then to prepare a few elements before hand, at the first `document.onclick` event.

Comment: @Kaiido could you please make sample with my code. I didn't get how to "allow from inside an user-gesture event. "